# General Questions about NeuralNetworks

Tags: neural-network

I have some general questions about NNs and their training in hope that you can answer them:
Lets propose, that Ive got an untrained NN with n hidden Layers and m neurons in it. I want to train the network to, eg recognice voice and so words. How can I make this possible when my sound input doesnt always have the same length (eg one is 1 second the other one is 5)? How many layers and what type should my NN be (Recurrent,LSTM,CNNs etc)? Are there any other training algorithms than the normal backpropagation ( I thought about having a NN with just one neuron in each Layer and then let grow new one till the problem could be solved)? And finally is it recommended/helpfull to make connections between the neurons of eg Layer 2 to Layer 4?

Thank you about your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid question, for your record.

You should definitely use a recurrent network for voice recognition. So that means you output say 1/100 of a second one by one. So for one second, you activate the network 100 times for one second of data.

Using an LSTM will make sure that patterns over large time lags are remembered, so the network will essentially rememember (useful) parts from previous inputs.

How many layers you should use is dependant on what exactly you want to recognize. But because voice recognition is not one of the easiest classification tasks, it will have to be a large deep network (combine convolutional with LSTM).

What you proposed, evolving the network one node by one, is basically called neuroevolution. Libraries such as [Neataptic](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic) support the evolution of networks towards a certain solution.

Yes, that could definitely help. But this can purely be found out by trial and error.

**PS:** I strongly recommend to start on an easier task to develop an understanding of neural networks.